# Visual Studio 2012 gives ridiculous errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

My visual studio doesn't build the solution if any of the following errors occurs:

```
1. Invalid spacing around ';'
2. All private methods must be declared after protected.
3. Constructor must be placed before method declarations.
4. Must use curly brackets in if condition.
5. Use string.empty instead of "".
```

Now I know we should follow correct coding practice, but I'm working on an old code that has these kinds of things. Its hard to change each and every file. How can I stop VS from giving these kinds of errors?

Comment: Well presumably you've got some sort of code analysis configured - but we can't tell what that is, because we can't look at your configuration and you haven't given us the *complete* details of the errors (including error codes).

Comment: @Tahreem you should try disabling the automatic `code analysis` feature of VS2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're using Stylecop on a non-compliant solution.
Create a setting file 'Settings.StyleCop' in the directory containing the *.sln file.
Add the following contents to the file:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Comment: The solution is indeed using Stylecop. Your solution worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

This is either caused by a plugin like Resharper or StyleCop. You can turn off some of these warnings or disable the plugin completely.